# Issues with Vim when bulk copy-pasting (yank/putting)

Tags: vim

I've been using Vim for around 7 months now, I mainly code in javascript but occasionally bash or python. I've picked up lot of tricks for using it and often go off the "if i can;t do it, find out how" or "if i think something can be improved find out how". I find it very difficult to do large restructures of files, moving blocks of code from on place in a file to another. I've tried using `:vsplit`to make things slightly easier. But it still feels clunky. What is the best way, or *a way* to move relatively large blocks (10-30 lines) of code, around a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way would be:

1. cut the block you want to move, either directly (`di{` for example) or after a visual selection (`vipd` for example).
2. move to where you want that block to be and paste.

And I don't see anything "clunky" about it.

How do you do it right now and why is it clunky?

Anyway, behold the beauty of Ex commands:

```
:'<,'>m33    <-- move the currently selected text to after line 33
:50,62m19    <-- move lines 50 to 62 to after line 19
:-23,+15m13  <-- move 13th line above to 15th line below to after line 13
:'{,'}m'a    <-- move the current paragraph to after mark a
:?^foo?,'bm. <-- move 1st line matching ^foo upward to mark b to after the current line
```

Oh god… See `:exusage`, `:help :move` and `:help range`.

Note that Vim has ways to help you navigate around:

- marks, `ma` to place mark `a`, `'a` to jump to mark `a`, see `:help mark-motions`
- the jumplist, `<C-o>` to jump back, `<C-i>` to jump forth, see `:help jumplist`

Comment: i was doing something more like `V20jd` move where I want and then paste, it just didn't seem right i'm not sure why.. i just tried the `vip`, what exactly does that do, blocks to the same indent? and what was the meaning of `di{`. Thanks for this answer it's clear and goes beyond what i asked so I appreciate it. I think i'll learn to use marks before Ex commands!!

Comment: `ip` is the "paragraph" text-object, a "paragraph" is made of every line between two blank lines. `i{` is another text-object for `{}` blocks. Read `:help motion.txt`, it will *blow* your mind. Direct action (`d20j`) is better than action after selection (`v20jd`) but it needs a bit of practice.